# Char array - why do we need +1 byte for sentinel value?

Tags: c++, array

Can anyone explain why do we need
 +1 byte for sentinel value?
As we know that 1 char = 1 byte so if we declare an array such as char a[50] why I can't store 50 chars instead of 49?

Comment: You *can* store 50 characters.  That is, of course, unless you allocate the last character to be a sentinel value.

Comment: Exactly why do I need 1 byte for sentinel value as I know that to store char of [50] I need 50 byte so why do we need 1 byte for \0

Comment: So that your strings don't have to be *exactly* 49 characters long (the sentinel character isn't always located at the end of the array).

Comment: You should use java or c#.

Comment: Don't make me come over there, @Erik :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: ar ar ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically C++ users prefer to use `std::string` where possible. Your question stems from lower-level C-programming and native types (which of course are still relevant in C++, but anyways)

Bottom-line, when you pass C-strings around you're simply passing the address of the first byte of the string. A lot of commonly-used string manipulation functions have something internally like this:

```
char* c;
for (c = str; *c != 0; ++c) {
    // Do something
}
```

When you're starting out programming in C/C++ you may be tempted to say "I know this string is 50 bytes long". But do you really?

```
char myStr[50] = "My Name Is Assimilater";
```

It's pretty common to allocate more than the exact number of bytes you need. You wouldn't want `printf` to copy any garbage characters after "Assimilater" to the console, now would you?

C-String buffers also tend to get reused to store many strings over their lifetime; this isn't a problem so long as the buffer is big enough to handle any string you intend to throw at it.

This, coupled with the fact that an algorithm may go off into `myStr[51]` and beyond if not given a sentinel to stop at, makes the presence of a sentinel value important.

Answer (score 1):

You need one byte for a sentinel value, because that sentinel value is encoded as the termination character `\0` - which simply requires one byte to store.

That a sentinel value is used is just a design decision. There is no inherent need, there are [other options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)#Representations).

In C, it is simply "convention" to terminate *strings* as null-terminated *character arrays*.
Indeed, there is a difference:

A *character array* is just an array of character values. ['a', 'b', 'z'] is a character array with three characters.
If you know the array has three characters, you do not need to terminate it:

```
char cs[3] = {'a', 'b', 'z'};
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    std::cout << cs[i];
```

will print the *string* `abz`.

You can think of a *string* as a single entity *represented* by a character array.
That is, you can also have character arrays which are not strings, like you can have integer arrays which you never want to print.
However, you always want a string to be represented as a character array.
(In short: strings are always character arrays, bot not every character array is a string in C.)

It is infeasible to know the length of any string in advance.
Therefore, all (?) library function can handle strings of arbitrary length.
Now, how to represent such a string?
We know that we can represent a fixed-length string (such as "abz") as a fixed-length array (such as `char cs[3] = {'a', 'b', 'z'}`).

Therefore, it has simply been *decided* that a string with *n* is a character array that holds *at least* (*n*+1) characters, where the first character *n* characters are the actual content, and the (*n*+1st) character is a terminating character signalling "end of string".

There are several reasons for this decision - as there are also disadvantages.
One advantage is that you can re-use the memory (allocating new memory can be costly, therefore one can allocate a larger chunk of memory), as Assimilater pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

When working with data structures of varying length, there are a couple of common simple solutions: keep track of the length or keep a sentinel value.

Sentinel values have the advantage of being the same size as the data. Therefore the sentinel can easily be used in the data stream. However, you constantly need to be on the watch for the sentinel value as you process the data.

Keeping a length makes many operations faster and easier (you don’t have to examine each value) however, the length has to live outside of the data. There are a couple of downsides to tracking the length. First you have to have a place to put the length that travels with your data. (See `std::string`). The type of the length also determines the maximum length of your data; is an `int` large enough? a `long`? Sentinels don’t have this limitation.

Even if you have a fixed size data structure you may have to interact with functions that assume a variable sized data structure. Most of the standard library string manipulation functions come in two flavors, sentinel based and length based. (Length based is often favored in order to prevent buffer overflows.)

Of course, the fact that the C/C++ compiler has sentinel strings built-in persuades most developers to just use that capability. But that only works for arrays of characters. You must account for sentinels, length, etc for other data types.

Of course, this is all useful knowledge, but the right answer is to use standard library containers like `std::string`, `std::vector` and friends. These containers are efficient and effective at managing data and length with fewer worries.

Comment: In case anybody's wondering, a 16-bit `int` is usually enough, permitting up to 65,535 characters in a string, a 32-bit `int` is probably enough, but sometimes you may come across a > 4 billion character file, and if a 64 bit `long` is insufficient for you, you might want to take a look at the *two* massive data centers you've got just to store your 18+ Exabyte string on disk, and consider if you might be doing something wrong.